# Align listbox items horizontally

Tags: windows-phone-7, alignment, listboxitems

I want to show a listbox with two items for each row.

You can see an example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/stephanc/WindowsLiveWriter/WindowsPhone7PanoramaControl_FF66/panorama-ctrl_3.jpg).

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="FriendsGrid">
    <ListBox x:Name="FriendsList" Margin="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FriendsDataTemplate}"/>
</Grid>

<DataTemplate x:Key="FriendsDataTemplate">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="183"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="FriendAvatar" Margin="1,1,11,11" Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Width="173" Height="173"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="FriendName" Margin="0" Text="{Binding FriendName}" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,10,0" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

But I see one ListBoxItem for each row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use a `WrapPanel` as the `ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: It's `ItemsPanel` actually! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx